# How can I add a data of size more than 2 mb as a single entry in cosmos db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

As there is a size limit for cosmsos db for single entry of data, how can I add a data of size more than 2 mb as a single entry?

Comment: Please do visit our data modelling documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example. If your document size is that big chances are there is something not entirely right with the design or maybe there are parts of your data (binary maybe?) that should be stored externally, like Azure Storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2MB limit is a hard-limit, not expandable. You'll need to work out a different model for your storage. Also, depending on how your data is encoded, it's likely that the actual limit will be under 2MB (since data is often expanded when encoded).

If you have content within an array (the typical reason why a document would grow so large), consider refactoring this part of your data model (perhaps store references to other documents, within the array, vs the subdocuments themselves). Also, with arrays, you have to deal with an "unbounded growth" situation: even with documents under 2MB, if the array can keep growing, then eventually you'll run into a size limit issue.